# error while installing scipy on Python 2.7.13

Tags: windows-10

I have installed python 2.7.13, installed numpy and matplotlib with command "pip install numpy" and "pip install matplotlib" respectively, But with scipy it's not like that. Here is error which m getting. Please suggest something.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZmlw.jpg)

Comment: Is ```lapack``` correctly installed?

Comment: error resolved. Thanks